# Proper answer numbering for sub problems in book class file

Tags: enumitem, books

I'm trying to create a latex file to present both the problems and their solutions at the end of the document.
Everything looks good except one thing, i.e., the **answer numbering** for multiple problems mentioned in a question. Anyone knows how to fix the numbering. 
Please check, the MWE is given below.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{tasks}
%
% Set the Show Answers Boolean
\newboolean{showAns}
\setboolean{showAns}{false}
\newcommand{\showAns}{\setboolean{showAns}{true}}
%
% The length of the Answer line
\newlength{\answerlength}
\newcommand{\anslen}[1]{\settowidth{\answerlength}{#1}}
%
% ans command that indicates space for an answer or shows the answer in red
\newcommand{\ans}[1]{\settowidth{\answerlength}{\hspace{2ex}#1\hspace{2ex}}%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{showAns}}%
    {\textcolor{red}{\underline{\hspace{2ex}#1\hspace{2ex}}}}%
    {\underline{\hspace{\answerlength}}}}%

% Formatting how multiple choices Questions are formated.
\settasks{counter-format={tsk[A])}}
%
% Some commands for the Exercise Question package
\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{Q~\arabic{Question}.\ }
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{} %no header
\renewcommand{\QuestionBefore}{2em} %Space above each Q
\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{1cm} % Indent after Q number
% To create the list of answers with tocloft... 
\newcommand{\listanswername}{Answers}
\newlistof[Question]{answer}{Answers}{\listanswername}
% Creates a TOC for Answers
\newcounter{prevQ}
\newcommand{\answer}[1]{\refstepcounter{answer}%
    \ans{#1}%
    \ifnum\theQuestion=\theprevQ%
    \addcontentsline{Answers}{answer}{\protect\numberline{}#1}% don't include the Q number
    \else%
    \addcontentsline{Answers}{answer}{\protect\numberline{\theQuestion}#1}%
    \setcounter{prevQ}{\value{Question}}%
    \fi%
}%
%tocloft formatting listofanswers
\renewcommand{\cftAnswerstitlefont}{\bfseries\large}
\renewcommand{\cftanswerdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\cftpagenumbersoff{answer} 
\addtolength{\cftanswernumwidth}{10pt}

%%%% DOCUMENT START HERE %%%%%
\begin{document}
\showAns  %%% uncomment it to see the answers with the questions 
\begin{Exercise}    
\Question Fill in the blanks:
\begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $1 + \answer{7} = 8$ 
    \task $4  - \answer{0} = 4$ 
    \task $3 + \answer{9} = 12$ 
    \task $13 - \answer{6} = 7$     
\end{tasks}
\Question Solve $2+3=$~\answer{$5$}
\Question 9 + 6 = 15. Is it True?~\answer{False}    
\end{Exercise}
\listofanswer  %%% uncomment to see the answer at the end 
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: see solution with `task` below.

---

This is a solution with `subQuestion` instead of `task`, with the disadvantage that the subquestions are not set in two columns.

The idea is to check for three cases in the `\answer` command: a new question without subquestions, a new question with subquestions, or a subquestion within the current question. In the first case you print the question number, in the second case you print the question number and the subquestion number, and in the third case you print only the subquestion number.

To align the numbers the width of the current question number is added. This can normally be done with `\phantom` but that does not work well within `\protect\numberline`, so `\settowidth` is used instead.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{exercise}
%\usepackage{tasks}
%
% Set the Show Answers Boolean
\newboolean{showAns}
\setboolean{showAns}{false}
\newcommand{\showAns}{\setboolean{showAns}{true}}
%
% The length of the Answer line
\newlength{\answerlength}
\newcommand{\anslen}[1]{\settowidth{\answerlength}{#1}}
%
% ans command that indicates space for an answer or shows the answer in red
\newcommand{\ans}[1]{\settowidth{\answerlength}{\hspace{2ex}#1\hspace{2ex}}%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{showAns}}%
    {\textcolor{red}{\underline{\hspace{2ex}#1\hspace{2ex}}}}%
    {\underline{\hspace{\answerlength}}}}%

% Formatting how multiple choices Questions are formated.
%\settasks{counter-format={tsk[A])}}
%
% Some commands for the Exercise Question package
\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{Q~\arabic{Question}.\ }
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{} %no header
\renewcommand{\QuestionBefore}{2em} %Space above each Q
\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{1cm} % Indent after Q number
% To create the list of answers with tocloft... 
\newcommand{\listanswername}{Answers}
\newlistof[Question]{answer}{Answers}{\listanswername}
% Creates a TOC for Answers
\newcounter{prevQ}
\newlength{\myquestionwd}% length to store question number width
\newcommand{\answer}[1]{\refstepcounter{answer}%
    \ans{#1}%
    \ifnum\theQuestion=\theprevQ% subquestion within current question
    \addcontentsline{Answers}{answer}{\protect\numberline{\settowidth{\myquestionwd}{\theQuestion.}\hspace{\myquestionwd}\thesubQuestion}#1}% don't include the Q number
    \else%
    \ifnum\value{subQuestion}>0% new question with subquestions
    \addcontentsline{Answers}{answer}{\protect\numberline{\theQuestion.\thesubQuestion}#1}%
    \setcounter{prevQ}{\value{Question}}%
    \else% new question without subquestions
    \addcontentsline{Answers}{answer}{\protect\numberline{\theQuestion}#1}%
    \setcounter{prevQ}{\value{Question}}%
    \fi%
    \fi%
}%
%tocloft formatting listofanswers
\renewcommand{\cftAnswerstitlefont}{\bfseries\large}
\renewcommand{\cftanswerdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\cftpagenumbersoff{answer} 
\addtolength{\cftanswernumwidth}{10pt}

%%%% DOCUMENT START HERE %%%%%
\begin{document}
\showAns  %%% uncomment it to see the answers with the questions 
\begin{Exercise}    
\Question Fill in the blanks:
%\begin{tasks}(2)
    \subQuestion $1 + \answer{7} = 8$ 
    \subQuestion $4  - \answer{0} = 4$ 
    \subQuestion $3 + \answer{9} = 12$ 
    \subQuestion $13 - \answer{6} = 7$     
%    \task $1 + \answer{7} = 8$ 
%    \task $4  - \answer{0} = 4$ 
%    \task $3 + \answer{9} = 12$ 
%    \task $13 - \answer{6} = 7$
%\end{tasks}
\Question Solve $2+3=$~\answer{$5$}
\Question 9 + 6 = 15. Is it True?~\answer{False}    
\end{Exercise}
\listofanswer  %%% uncomment to see the answer at the end 
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Solution with `task`: basically the same, but now using the expl3 syntax `\int_to_Alph:n \g__tasks_int` instead of `\thesubQuestion` to access the internal `tasks` counter `\g__tasks_int` and convert it into uppercase alphabetic letters. Testing this counter is done with `\int_compare:nNnTF`. Also, this counter does not automatically reset at the end of the `tasks` environment, so that is added with `\xapptocmd` from the `xpatch` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
%
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{exercise}
\usepackage{tasks}
\usepackage{xpatch}

% reset counter after tasks environment
\ExplSyntaxOn
\xapptocmd{\endtasks}{\int_gzero:N \g__tasks_int}{}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%
% Set the Show Answers Boolean
\newboolean{showAns}
\setboolean{showAns}{false}
\newcommand{\showAns}{\setboolean{showAns}{true}}
%
% The length of the Answer line
\newlength{\answerlength}
\newcommand{\anslen}[1]{\settowidth{\answerlength}{#1}}
%
% ans command that indicates space for an answer or shows the answer in red
\newcommand{\ans}[1]{\settowidth{\answerlength}{\hspace{2ex}#1\hspace{2ex}}%
    \ifthenelse{\boolean{showAns}}%
    {\textcolor{red}{\underline{\hspace{2ex}#1\hspace{2ex}}}}%
    {\underline{\hspace{\answerlength}}}}%

% Formatting how multiple choices Questions are formated.
\settasks{counter-format={tsk[A])}}
%
% Some commands for the Exercise Question package
\renewcommand{\QuestionNB}{Q~\arabic{Question}.\ }
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{} %no header
\renewcommand{\QuestionBefore}{2em} %Space above each Q
\setlength{\QuestionIndent}{1cm} % Indent after Q number
% To create the list of answers with tocloft... 
\newcommand{\listanswername}{Answers}
\newlistof[Question]{answer}{Answers}{\listanswername}
% Creates a TOC for Answers
\newcounter{prevQ}
\newlength{\myquestionwd}
\ExplSyntaxOn%
\newcommand{\answer}[1]{\refstepcounter{answer}%
    \ans{#1}%
    \ifnum\theQuestion=\theprevQ% subquestion within current question
     \addcontentsline{Answers}{answer}{\protect\numberline{\settowidth{\myquestionwd}{\theQuestion.}\hspace{\myquestionwd}\int_to_Alph:n \g__tasks_int} #1}% don't include the Q number
    \else%
    \int_compare:nNnTF{\g__tasks_int}>{0}{% new question with subquestions
     \addcontentsline{Answers}{answer}{\protect\numberline{\theQuestion.\int_to_Alph:n \g__tasks_int}#1}%
     \setcounter{prevQ}{\value{Question}}%
     }{% new question without subquestions
    \addcontentsline{Answers}{answer}{\protect\numberline{\theQuestion.}#1}%
    \setcounter{prevQ}{\value{Question}}%
    }%
    \fi%
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff%
%tocloft formatting listofanswers
\renewcommand{\cftAnswerstitlefont}{\bfseries\large}
\renewcommand{\cftanswerdotsep}{\cftnodots}
\cftpagenumbersoff{answer} 
\addtolength{\cftanswernumwidth}{10pt}

%%%% DOCUMENT START HERE %%%%%
\begin{document}
\showAns  %%% uncomment it to see the answers with the questions 
\begin{Exercise}    
\Question Fill in the blanks:
\begin{tasks}(2)
    \task $1 + \answer{7} = 8 $
    \task $4  - \answer{0} = 4$
    \task $3 + \answer{9} = 12$
    \task $13 - \answer{6} = 7$
\end{tasks}
\Question Solve $2+3=$~\answer{$5$}
\Question 9 + 6 = 15. Is it True?~\answer{False}    
\end{Exercise}
\listofanswer  %%% uncomment to see the answer at the end 
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: If the answer is too long and needs to be wrapped, how to do this?